# nodejs exporting function email.send doesn't execute

Tags: node.js

Have mailer.js below but when importing 'var email = require('./models/mailer')'  my 'email.send' doesn't execute ?

```
var config = require('./config');
var email = require('emailjs');

var server  = email.server.connect({
host:    config.smptRelay
});

module.exports = function send() {
server.send({
    text: config.emailText,
    from: config.emailFrom,
    to: config.emailTo,
    subject: config.emailSubject
    }, function (err, message) { /*console.log(err || message); */
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting the function directly, as `module.exports`, and not as a property of it. Just call it as `email()`.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it to let others know that it worked.